# How can I use COMMIT in stored procedure in DB2 LUW

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

```
CREATE TABLE T1(c1 varchar(10));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FOO()
BEGIN
FOR C AS WITH TT (C1) AS (VALUES (1) , (2) , (3)) SELECT C1 FROM TT
DO
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('aaa');
COMMIT;
END FOR;
END
@
```

When I execute this stored procedure, I get this error:

> db2 "call foo()"
>   SQL0501N  The cursor specified in a FETCH statement or CLOSE statement is not 
>   open or a cursor variable in a cursor scalar function reference is not open.

How can I do commit for each insert?

Comment: Side note: you need to be careful about using `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK` inside a procedure, because it can make composition difficult - if another procedure call this one, you may end up committing/rolling back changes you weren't aware of.  If you _must_ `COMMIT` here, it's probably better to use an [autonomous transaction](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0907autonomoustransactions/index.html).  Otherwise, let the caller handle the scope.  Also, that statement can be written without the use of a loop, but it's unclear if your real one can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COMMIT` closes all open cursors that were declared without the `HOLD` option, including the cursor implicitly created by the `FOR` statement.

Here's the change you need to make:

```
FOR C AS cur1 CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
WITH TT (C1) AS (VALUES (1) , (2) , (3)) SELECT C1 FROM TT
DO
  INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('aaa');
  COMMIT;
END FOR;
```

[Documentation reference.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004238.html?pos=2)